# What does "pick up more than a little caring cachet en route" mean?

Tags: meaning

I read an article by Margarette Driscoll, there are parts that I don't understand. I would appreciate it if you could help me.

> Two hundred years ago, all the women might have been trudging down the lane from the manor house bearing a basket of goodies for the poor. These days, they can jet to their particular good cause and—who would deny them this?—pick up more than a little caring cachet en route.

I need to know the meaning of the last sentence. "Pick up....." 
Thanks a billion

Comment: What is the source? As written, the spacing and punctuation needs to be cleaned up a bit.

Comment: Nice find in terms of a highly idiomatic passage with lots of terms that are hard to find in textbooks! :) Here "cachet" means prestige or reputation ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cachet#English)). "caring cachet" would be "an aura/reputation of being caring (people)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting example, talking about helping the poor or charities.

> Two hundred years ago, all the women might have been trudging down the lane
>   *A long time ago, before the age of social media, one might walk down the road*
>
> from the manor house bearing a basket of goodies for the poor.
>   *from one's privileged life to help the poor (and this act would go unnoticed).*
>
> These days, they can jet to their particular good cause
>   *in these modern days of fast transport, one can support their favorite cause*
>
> and — who would deny them this?—pick up more than a little caring cachet en route.
>   *and - who would blame them - get credit and attention for helping and caring*

The implication of the article may be that those who might be *attention seeking* have the tools these days to tell the world about what they are doing, and may be motivated more by the *attention* (Facebook ***"likes"***) than by the *act of giving*.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really got the point. You saved me! I went through a lot of difficulties to find the answer. I gain thank you wholeheartedly.

Comment: Keep studying and you will know it on your own!